# iBus preferences is not shown in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ibus

iBus Preferences is not shown in Ubuntu 13.10, I already configured iBus to add new keyboard but it is not showing. ibus-setup command and it only shows next input method, there is not enable and disable option, how to fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to check out Region & Settings panel in the System Settings, apparently they are moving all the settings there.

Edit: apparently the name of the settings applet is changed to Text Entry for now